# Bot is not assigning roles. I am getting error missing permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am getting error when someone joins. I created a bot for college to assign a role according to their names. But I am getting error of Missing Permissions. Below is error which i am getting. Help me with it.
(node:6660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:6660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a 
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6660) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: I have given administrator role to my bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#limitations-and-oddities), giving your bot administrator permissions doesn't allow it to bypass role hierarchy.

> The `ADMINISTRATOR` permission being granted does not skip any hierarchical check!

The most basic solution would be to drag your bot's role above all other roles and give it the `Manage Roles` permission. Another solution to this issue would be you giving the bot a role higher than the role it is assigning with `Manage Roles` permissions